# system() with dot doesn't create the .dot file

Tags: c, dot

I'm trying to make my code use the command `dot -Tpng -o file.png file.dot` but it doesn't seem to work with `system("dot -Tpng -o file.png file.dot")`.
It returns 0 but no files are created.
I also tried to do `execl("dot","-Tpng -o file.png file.dot",NULL)`but I don't think this is the correct syntax or way to do it.

Is there a way to make my C program (on Linux) execute the command line ?
Here is my code :

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.dot","w");
fprintf(f, "digraph graphname {\n\ta->b [label = 1]\n}");
system("dot -Tpng -o file.png file.dot");
fclose(f);
return 0;
```

EDIT  :
I moved the `fclose(f)`before the `system()` call and it worked.
I guess it had something to do with f not being closed.

Comment: you want to do it on linux or windows?

Comment: `system()` is ok. There must be something in the environment of the calling program that caueses the problem (I don't know dot, so I can't guess what). `execl()` would be `ececl( "dot", "dot", "-Tpng", "-o", ...., NULL )` -- every argument as an individual string staring with the program name (`argv[0]` in a C `main()`). Be aware that `exec...()` *overload* the calling process

Comment: There's always the question of *where* is your program is trying to create that file. Try `system("pwd")` to see the working directory.

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem. without our having to guess as to what your program is actually doing.

Comment: I want to do it on Linux and `system("pwd")` returns the correct path (the one where my c files are and where I'm doing everything)